# Pressing the dialog close icon( the X) causes error java

Tags: java, dialog

I am new in software development and learning java. When I close the dialog box while pressing x button it gives me an exception. How can I stop this exception. If anybody could help that would be great.
Thanks 
Haris

```
private void exitProgram() {        

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit", "confirm", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION ,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        showMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: What Java version are you using ? This looks good maybe it's in your `showMenu();` method

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION||result == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
            showMenu();
```

Very simple